# how to add date after text in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell **B8** that is currently formatted with the *Currency Format*, in a sheet that we will simply call **Sheet1**. I am sure this is something that I will need to accomplish in VBA, but what would be the process of having Excel add the following to the end of the cell B8:

`as of 'MM/DD/YY'` where the date is today (not concerned if the date auto updates or not, such as if I were to save the workbook after VBA entering today's date and if I were to reopen tomorrow it could either show the original date or the new date - does not make a difference as it will get saved in a non editable format)

So with consideration that the cell is formatted with the Currency format (which excludes decimals btw), by me entering a number such as "**10000**", the cell should display the following:

```
$10,000 as of 03/03/16
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try recording a macro where you apply a "Custom" format.

Comment: If you can use a helper cell, if "10000" is in A1 and the date is in B1, you can use this in C1: `=Text(A1,"$#,##0.00") & " as of " & Text(B1,"mm/dd/yy")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retain the raw numerical value typed into B8 while displaying the currency symbol and decimal places as well as the *'as of mm/dd/yy'* portion but the date will be display only.

Copy this code and paste it into the worksheet's code sheet (right-click the ws name tab, View Code).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B8")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim str As String
        str = Range("B8").NumberFormat
        If CBool(InStr(1, str, "\a\s of", vbTextCompare)) Then _
            ThisWorkbook.DeleteNumberFormat NumberFormat:=str
        str = Format(Date, " \a\s of dd-mmm-yyyy")
        str = StrConv(str, vbUnicode)
        str = Join(Split(str, vbNullChar), Chr(92))
        str = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)
        str = "$#,##0" & str & ";[Red]($#,##0)" & str
        Range("B8").NumberFormat = str
        'Debug.Print str
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

You will not build up a number of useless custom number formats because each is deleted before assigning a new one; even if it is the same one. The value in the B8 cell remains available for calculation and comparison.

[image: cnf_as_of]

Note the number-like right-alignment in the cell. If the column is not wide enough to display the entire blurb, you will end up with ########.

Answer (score 1):

Select any cell and use a macro like this to apply the number format with today's date. This format is static and will not change (unless you re-run the macro).

I derived this from a recorded macro, where I used a "Custom" format and applied a simple string to it, like so:

[image]

That gives me some basic code like:

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0_)"" foo"";[Red]($#,##0)"" foo"""
```

Note the double quotation marks. That part is a little tricky to work with sometimes. Then modified it for this criteria:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
Dim dt As String
dt = """ as of " & Format(Now(), "[$-409]mmmm d, yyyy;@") & """"

    Selection.NumberFormat = _
        "$#,##0_)" & dt & ";[Red]($#,##0)" & dt
End Sub
```

Comment: I did get that to work - however, is there a way to auto populate as soon as I type a number in that field? Or it could even be there if the field is blank if it needed to be. On a different project I used a VBA script that would copy text entered in a specific cell to the tab/sheet name immediate upon pressing enter in the cell. Here is that code:

`Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address(0, 0) = "F6" Then
    Sh.Name = Sh.Range("F6").Value
  End If
End Sub`

EDIT: Evidently comments do not allow line breaks. Sorry for the messy code.

Comment: In your Worksheet_Activate procedure, just add a statement like `Call Macro2` to call the other procedure (modify macro name if needed)

Comment: Oops, or your `Worksheet_Change` event. Basically you just need to *call* this procedure on demand, and you can of course do this manually from the Macros menu, or from built-in *event* procedures like `Worksheet_Change`.  Further, it can be modified ife needed to only operate on specific range of cells, etc.